Getting error (DRM: DDC responded, but no EDID) on my Dell Precision 3530 laptop
Today upon rebooting my laptop, suddenly I was unable to boot into Ubuntu normally with GUI mode and was getting this error, but was able to go into recovery mode and access the shell from there.

I'm not sure what went wrong, but I updated the firmware through Ubuntu Firmware Updater, though it was working fine and the update was successful, so I don't know why I'm getting this strange error now.
Usually I would have gone straight into reinstalling OS in the hopes it would fix things, but in this case strangely somehow when I first installed Ubuntu a while back, it stopped showing my USB bootable drive in the Boot Sequence in the BIOS, the very same USB from which I've installed Ubuntu in the first place, I've checked right after, it just won't show up, but it worked normally and fine when accessing it through the File Menu after booting into the OS.
